# How to get rid of select highlight on mobile for Chakra UI Select components

Tags: css, reactjs, select, mobile, chakra-ui

I have Chakra UI  component which is biult like below:

```
<Select
          icon={<DropdownIcon />}
          value={yearsRange[date.getFullYear()]}
          onChange={handleYearChange}
          fontWeight="600"
          border="none"
          background="transparent"
          fontSize="20px"
          color={colors.primary}
          sx={{
            appearance: 'none',
            padding: '0 5px',
            paddingInlineStart: 'none',
            WebkitPaddingStart: 'none',
            '& + .chakra-select__icon-wrapper': {
              order: -1,
              position: 'static',
              transform: 'none',
            },
          }}
          rootProps={{
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
        >
          {yearsRange.map((year) => (
            <StyledOption key={year} value={year}>
              {year}
            </StyledOption>
          ))}
        </Select>
```

I cannot figure out how to get rid of higlighted picked option, it's for mobile project. It's not with light blue color which actually looks quite ugly.

I have option styled this way,

```
export const StyledOption = styled.option`
  &:checked {
    background-color: ${colors.primary};
    color: ${colors.white};
  }
`;
```

But it makes it visible only for miliseconds once I choosed different option.
When I open Select component it looks like this:
[image]

Would appreciate Your help.